Circular progress bar - How to animate from green point to red point?

I want to animate this shape. I want it to animate from green start point to red end point, like there is nothing and then the object will appear from the green point, growing to the red point.

First: there is plenty of animation information on this site to search for and answer your question... try to search before posting.   Answer hint, look at a circular curve to fit the path, and then for the object Constraints, Follow Path of the curve with Follow Curve enabled.  example

As I understand it, the circle is supposed to grow in animation from nothing to a full circle, counterclockwise, starting at the green point. I'm not sure if the Constraints, Follow Path helps here @james_t . I would try it with Geometry Nodes (like the tag of the question suggests ;-). The Trim Curve node can do the animation. I think the challenge is to create the dashed line on it and make it properly growing.

Should the dashes appear one by one or should they grow from nothing to full size? The first case is easy, I think, because you only have to place the cylinders on the points of the curve.

You can do this as suggested with Geometry Nodes.

Add a Curve > Circle (Shift+A) to the scene
rotate it by -90° along the Z-axis so the start and end points are at "the top" (Y-axis) in top view. Then Apply > Rotation (Ctrl+A).
add the following Geometry Nodes modifier (see below)
add keyframes for the Trim Curve > Start value so is goes from 1.0 to 0.0 within 60 frames for examples.
optional: In the Graph Editor, set Channel > Extrapolation Mode to Linear (Shift+E) so that the cylinders all will appear at the same speed.

Geometry Nodes node tree for a round progress bar:

Notes:

the node Transform Geometry with the value Rotation > Z of 5.625d is required to align the gaps on the X-axis and Y-axis. Otherwise, the bars are centered on the axes. The value 5.625d can be entered as 360d/32/2. 360° is the full circle, 32 is the number of bars, and 2 to get it centered.
there is a little flaw: the bars/cylinders at the start and end points are not properly aligned to the curve's normal for some reason. The start point is removed anyway, but if you look closely, you can see that the end point (which is the start of the animation) is tangentially aligned. If it bothers you, you can select them with the Endpoint Selection node and rotate it slightly.
speaking of the tangent, you could replace the Normal + Vector Rotate nodes with a single Curve Tangent node to get the same alignment of the cylinders. (I forgot that there is also this node.)

